# Is there a python wrapper for a FastLZ implementation

Tags: python, compression

Looking to use FastLZ in Python, or something similar. Tried Google and didn't find anything. Wondering if there is another algorithm with similar performance available in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using `ctypes` to call directly into `fastlz.so` (or `.dll` as the case may be)?  It seems to have only 3 entry points, so wrapping them in `ctypes` should not be hard.  Yes, SWIG or a custom C API wrapper should be almost as trivial, but `ctypes` lets you start experimenting right now even if you don't have a compiler (as long as you can get a working DLL/so of FastLZ for your platform)... hard to beat!-)

Answer (score 0):

[Blosc](https://github.com/Blosc/python-blosc) exposes FastLZ and several other compressors in Python.